# Looking for a "standard-mollifier"-type function

Tags: analysis, functions

I'm looking for a function $\phi$ that behaves like a standard mollifier, in particular it should be positive, even, $\phi(0)=1$, $\phi(x)=0$ for $|x|>1$ and $C^\infty$. The (scaled) mollifier
\begin{equation}
\epsilon(x)=e^{1-1/(1-x^2)}
\end{equation}
would do the job but the problem is that I'm looking for a function *defined on all $\mathbb{R}$ by a single formula*.

The standard mollifier is defined by cases (i.e. it's set to zero for $|x|>1$).

I think there is no such formula. Any ideas? Such function should resemble a "thin" gaussian
\begin{equation}
\phi(x)=e^{-x^2/\sigma}
\end{equation}
for very small $\sigma$; this function is anyway no good because it's not exactly zero outside the unit circle...

Comment: What do you mean by *formula*? It shouldn't be hard to concoct a formula for a function $h(x)$ that is $1$ exactly when $|x| < 1$ and $0$ otherwise. Then you could take $\epsilon(x) h(x)$.

Comment: I would need a function which is not defined by cases...Actually I think it's not possible, since such a function should have a continuum of zeros, and I guess it's not possible (unless we define the function to be exactly zero in some interval)